# Get N number of images from gallery using intent

Tags: android

```
 public void getPhoto() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE,true);
        startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
    }
```

I tried this code and it ables user to get multiple images  but how to cap it at a speciic number.
I tried checking previous answers but could not find anything satisfying my question.

Comment: You can check out this library: https://github.com/siralam/BSImagePicker . This is so simple.

Comment: Indeed, that is not possible with that intent.

Comment: @NobanHasan Is there a similar way to get files(pdf,docs,xls)

Comment: Try this https://github.com/DroidNinja/Android-FilePicker . It works great.

Comment: Noban Hasan Thank you , you have been a huge help